# trying to upgrade to http2 via python socket

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I am trying to upgrade to http/2.0 using a python socket. I have already tried using the upgrade header like so: `Connection: Upgrade` then `Upgrade: h2c`. This makes the server respond with a http/1.1 200 OK response. I am now trying to use ALPN via the `ssl` module.
This is the code for attempting via ALPN:

```
 def connect_socket(self):

        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        context = ssl.create_default_context()

        context.set_alpn_protocols(['h2c'])

        while True:
            try:
                sock.connect(("twitter.com", 443))
                sock = context.wrap_socket(sock)
                return sock
                
            except:
                pass
```

This just hangs at `context.wrap_socket(sock)`. If i get rid of the context and just use `ssl.wrap_socket()` everything works and i can use HTTP/1.1 fine. The server does support it because using PyCurl's Verbose mode i can see that it uses HTTP/2.
I have tried using `h2c` `http/2.0` and `h2`.
Printing the exception i have been getting, turns out to be this:

```
[WinError 10056] A connect request was made on an already connected socket
```

Newest code that still does not upgrade:

```
def connect_socket(self):

        while True:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            context = ssl.create_default_context()

            context.set_alpn_protocols(['h2c'])

            context.check_hostname = False
            try:
                sock.connect(("twitter.com", 443))
                sock = context.wrap_socket(sock)
                return sock

            except Exception as e:
                sock.close()
                print(e)
```

This returns a socket with no errors, then this request is sent:

```
def test_send_data(self, sock):
        
        unencoded_string = 'GET /noah HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: twitter.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'
        
        sock.send(unencoded_string.encode())
```

This sends fine, and the important part of the response is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\ncache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate,
```

My question is: Why is it just hanging, and how can i fix it?

Comment: does `'h2'` change anything as opposed to `'h2c'`?

Comment: no, it turns out i was getting an exception. Look at edited question for details.

Comment: What's with the while loop? I believe you're hitting a different exception first, which passes on the exception, and then you get that you're already on the socket when you connect again because you're in a loop.

Comment: that worked, but its still not upgrading. Will update with code.

Comment: Whoops, accidentally deleted my comment before the most recent comment, which for posterity was "pass `server_hostname="twitter.com"` to `wrap_socket` and use h2 for the protocol. Should be OK. Get rid of the while loop and don't pass your exceptions."

Comment: i will do that, but i need to be able to upgrade successfully first. Passing server_hostname and setting it to False has the same results, tested.

Comment: How are you checking whether it's h2 or http/1.1? Trying it on my computer, `sock.selected_alpn_protocol()` states that the protocol is "h2"

Comment: well if i send a request and it contains HTTP/1.1 that would mean its infact HTTP/1.1 correct? or am i mssing something?

Comment: I'm not sure, unfortunately (this is about the extent of my ability to help here.).

Comment: thank you for your help, for some clarity, using 'h2' did not work and would hang. '''http/2.0" and "h2c" work fine.

Comment: I had a different experience, h2c hung but h2 didn't; from your error it looks like you're on Windows, and I'm on macOS---could potentially affect something here, but not sure.

Comment: turns out you were right. Using h2 AND NOT checking hostname hangs for me, but passing server_hostname will work. After that, my next error was actually in the recv function where i was looking for \r\n\r\n to break from the read loop and return the byte-string. I just realized this will not work, after printing the socket recv data If you would like, post the answer and i will accept+up-vote.

Comment: Excellent! Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some of your exception handling was giving you the wrong hints. If you encountered an exception, you'd have been trying to connect again, and at some point Windows complained about trying to connect to a socket that wasn't closed.

The ALPN protocol for HTTP/2 should be set to `h2`, and after that running your code gave me an error:

```
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

After adding that argument, I was able to get a response from the server and Python says that the connection is H2:

```py
import socket
import ssl


def connect_h2_socket(host):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context.set_alpn_protocols(["h2"])
    sock.connect((host, 443))
    sock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=host)
    return sock



s = connect_h2_socket("twitter.com")
print("Selected protocol:", s.selected_alpn_protocol())
print(s.recv())
```

Running this produces the following for me:

> ```
> Selected protocol: h2
> b'\x00\x00\x06\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00'
> ```

Comment: would you happen to know how to decompress the response via HPACK? i seem to be getting many errors

Comment: @Noah I don't know what HPACK is, probably better off asking a separate question!